# Multiple inputs in Elm?

Tags: elm

Is it possible in Elm to trigger multiple input handles with one event handler? For example, suppose I have the following:

```
button 
    [ type' "button", on "click" getAnything go.handle (\_ -> searchInput) ] 
    [ text "Go" ]
```

In this case, clicks on the Go button will send values to the `go` input. What I want is to send a different value to a different input on that same click event (say, the `go2` input).

Is there some way to say, combine inputs or have one input fan out to multiple signals?

Answer (score 1):

You can have one input fan out to multiple signals. I'm not aware of a way to combine inputs.

Fanning out would basically mean that you send your two different values to the same input by wrapping them in a tuple. Then fanning out your input to multiple signals would involve something like:

```
signalUnzip : Signal (this,that) -> (Signal this, Signal that)
signalUnzip signal = (fst <~ signal, snd <~ signal)

go : Input (String,Int)
go = input ("",0)

(goFanoutPart1,goFanoutPart2) = signalUnzip go.signal
-- goFanoutPart1 : Signal String, goFanoutPart2 : Signal Int
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I ended up solving the issue in a slightly different way, by generating another signal on the same input, and just merging it with the original signal.

Comment: If you're curious, you can check out the cross-post here: http://www.reddit.com/r/elm/comments/2lbpk9/multiple_event_handlers/

Comment: @Andrew can you answer your own question here, and include some code? After reading the cross-post, I'm just more confused on what you wanted exactly...

Comment: Sorry for the late comment, but the original motivating use case was displaying a loading image while an Http request completed. My solution was to duplicate the signal using merge. You can see that in my Gist here which should compile in Elm 0.13: https://gist.github.com/smiley325/f1d2759dbe33af5d43e3, hopefully that explains more

Comment: Specifically, lines 58/59 where I use `go.signal` twice